# What was Captain Phasma's weapon?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In The Last Jedi Finn and Captain Phasma come face to face again, this time though they seem to have a pretty even fight at hand to hand combat. Throughout this fight Phasma uses a fancy metal pole. This seems to be made out of the same blaster deflecting material as her armour. It also appears to extend out of itself and still be smooth and resistant, even easily deflecting Finn's strikes.

What is this weapon?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) for Last Jedi offers the following info about her "*[quicksilver baton](http://www.starwars.com/databank/captain-phasma-s-baton)*".

> **QUICKSILVER BATON**
>
> *Phasma wields a quicksilver baton for close combat. The durable cylinder is made from a collapsible micromesh matrix held in a
>   containment field. When inactive, it condenses down to a small baton.
>   When active, it instantly expands to its full length.*

It also mentions that it never needs sharpening as the point is shaped by a field.

> [image]
>   <sub><sup>*"**Field-shaped spearpoint never dulls**"*</sup></sub>

You can see the relative length as well

> [image]

It's described thusly in the film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)

> *The ax cut her rifle in two. Finn grinned as his former commander
>   tossed the useless halves of her weapon away. But before he could
>   press his advantage, **Phasma yanked a short steel baton off her utility
>   belt.** A quick whiplike motion extended it into a double-ended spear as
>   long as she was tall.*

Apparently it's made of steel(!?), or at least something sufficiently steel-like as to meet that description.

Comment: The image isn't the clearest, does the full length one look to be solid? i.e. no cracks for where it could snap into place.

Comment: It looks solid. One of the features of "quicksilver" (mercury?) is that it's liquid metal.

Comment: Liquid at room temperature so I suppose the whole thing is bound by a field.

Comment: The quote says that it's a "micromesh matrix" not a liquid metal. My guess is that the mesh is probably very flexible on it's own and has a default shape that it only takes at full extension. You could either have a field pull the mesh into shape from the outside, or push it from the inside. It could be a combination. The field pushes the handle into shape, and then transitions to protect the impact surfaces. It's probably an adaptation of some precision repulsor technology.

Comment: @kettch - Sure. That's also a possibility.